# Orthonormal basis for Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

Suppose there is a hermitian  matrix.

Then, Can we always find out orthonormal basis for this matrix ?

And, Is there any relationship between hermitian matrix and hermitian transformation?

If matrix is hermitian, does that imply transformation is hermitian?

or

If the transformation is hermitian, then matrix of T is hermitian?

Comment: What is your definition of a Hermitian transformation, as opposed to a Hermitian matrix?

Comment: hermitian matrix is matrix is equal to conjugate transpose of A and Hermitian transformation is (T(x).y)=(x.T(y))

Comment: I noticed that If there is orthonormal basis for Matrix A and A is hermitian matrix, then transformation is also hermtiain. I want to see if this is true for all hermitian matrix

Answer (score 1):

Yes; it is indeed true that a transformation if and only if its matrix is Hermitian (with respect to any orthonormal basis).

**Proof:** Let $A$ be the standard matrix associated with $T$.

Suppose that $A$ is Hermitian. Then for all $x,y$,
$$
\langle T(x),y \rangle = 
y^* (Ax) = (y^* A^*)x = (Ay)^*x = \langle x,T(y) \rangle
$$
as desired.

Suppose $T$ is Hermitian.  Then for all $x,y$, we have
$$
y^*Ax = \langle T(x),y \rangle = 
\langle x,T(y)\rangle = 
(Ay)^*x = y^*A^* x
$$
It follows that $A = A^*$

Furthermore, by the [spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem), every Hermitian matrix has an orthonormal eigenbasis.

Comment: So, If transformation is hermitian, there exists orthonormal basis and matrix of T with relative to this orthonormal basis is hermtiain?

Comment: If a transformation is Hermitian, then its matrix with respect to **every** orthonormal basis will be Hermitian.

Comment: To make sure I understand it correctly,  If there is hermitian matrix, then there always exists an orthonormal basis and therefore transformation is hermtiain. If transformation is hermitian, then there exists an orthnormal baisis that matrix of T with this basis is hermitian matrix.

Comment: You keep saying "there exists an orthonormal basis", and I don't think it means what you think it means.  Every vector space with an inner product has an orthonormal basis, and that has nothing to do with any property of a transformation on that space.

Comment: I am sorry. The reason why I am confused is that every hermitian matrix is similar to diagonal matrix with its eigenvalues. Is that because Transformation is hermitian? There is a theorem saying that If transformation is hermitian, then there exists eigenvectors forming a orthonormal basis and matrix of this basis is diagonal.

Comment: Yes. If a transformation is Hermitian, there exists and orthonormal basis consisting of **eigenvectors** of the transformation.  If any transformation has a basis of eigenvectors, it is diagonal with respect to that basis.

Comment: Thank you. you helped me a lot